# Modifying Labels and Contents

Tags: csv, import, sas, export

I am trying to modify the existing .csv file and save a new version to another location. The task is to: 

1) put different labels to variable names 
2) conditionally modify contents of one of the variables

```
%let infile=/.../file.csv;
%let outfile=/.../new_file.csv;

data _null_ ;
  infile "&infile" dsd dlm=',' lrecl=2000 truncover ; 
  file "&outfile" dsd dlm='|' lrecl=200 ;
  length var1-var5 $161 ;
  input var1-var5 ;
  put (var1-var3 var5) (+0) ;
  label var1='#var1' var2='Variable 2';
  if var5 = 'donkey' then var3 = 'donkey '||var3 ;
run;
```

Do I need to actually import the initial file, make changes to it, and write it back after?

Comment: Depends on how you define 'import' what you're doing above can work, but you need to add a condition for the first row and make sure the variables are recoded BEFORE the put statement. In this case, you are writing them back out before you've changed Var3.  I also think the delimiters need to be defined in the PUT statement in this case but you can easily test that.

Answer (score 0):

CSV files do not have names or labels, just column headers. If you want to make changes to the column headers then change the values of the first line only.

```
%let infile=/.../file.csv;
%let outfile=/.../new_file.csv;

data _null_ ;
  infile "&infile" dsd dlm=',' lrecl=2000 truncover ; 
  file "&outfile" dsd dlm='|' lrecl=200 ;
  length var1-var5 $161 ;
  input var1-var5 ;
  if _n_=1 then do;
    var1='#var1'; var2='Variable 2';
  end;
  else do;
    if var5 = 'donkey' then var3 = 'donkey '||var3 ;
  end;
  put (var1-var3 var5) (+0) ;
run;
```